# How does Scala handle duplicate case classes?

Tags: scala, jvm

I'm trying to optimize the memory consumption of a Scala application which has a large tree structure storing nodes(case class) that could have duplicates. The tree structure is constructed by converting the following json format:

```
{
  "type": "tree",
  "left": {
    "type": "leaf",
    "id": "1",
    "content": "abc"
  },
  "right": {
    "type": "leaf",
    "id": "1",
    "content": "abc"
  }
}
```

to case classes

```
sealed abstract trait Node

case class Tree(
    left: Node
    right: Node
) extends Node

case class Leaf(
    id: String
    content: String
    ...
) extends Node
```

My optimization is to use a Map[String, Node] (using `id` as key) to cache distinct nodes while constructing the tree and avoid creating duplicate leaf node with the same `id`. However, by comparing the memory consumptions(by using Native Memory Tracking and Yourkit memory snapshot) before and after the change, I haven't noticed any memory decrease.

I'm wondering if Scala already reuses case classes that are the same internally thus my optimization is not needed.

Comment: No, Scala does not do this. But you're caching very small data structure in a map that consume its own memory, too. Maybe you don't significantly have overlaps in your data. Try counting the total number of leaves and checking the size of your map to see if you're really avoiding the creation of many objects.

Comment: No Scala does not do this. Neither is this expected behaviour for any sane programming language.

Comment: There is a means by which you can make the `apply` method for a case class memoize.  https://docs.google.com/document/d/18SfBKHBUQ96dLYs-WyfzSKCFT6jrNF8FunMfCn55yMY/pub  elaborates.

Comment: @LeviRamsey that document looks to be out of date. User-defined apply is allowed without ceremony since 2.12. It does mean the companion is no longer a Function.

Comment: Thanks folks, I think I know the problem. My original test was too noisy to tell the difference from the profiler. After cleaning up the tests, I can see the differences now. I wish there is a way to allow adding markers when profiling in order to know exactly what the program is doing in a specific period.

Answer (score 0):

Even though both your nodes are the same, Scala doesn't make their references point to a single object because they're really not the same, though they're case classes with the same values. Also, sometimes case classes have var's, and the nodes may be changed later, so it's unsafe to have them point to the same object.